# Getting SFDC ID from SaveResult returned by MuleSoft connector

Tags: groovy, salesforce, mule

I'm working on a POC using MuleSoft and SalesForce and was trying to make the flow more efficient.  Currently after creating a set of cases, I am executing another query to get the IDs of all the cases created.  I noticed when dumping the payload after the create that the IDs of each created case comes back as part of a SaveResult list, however the format does not look to be easily referenced as a map.  Since the IDs are being returned after the create, I can avoid an additional query just to get the IDs if I can parse them from the SaveResult.

This is an example returned as the #[payload] in Mule:

```
[[SaveResult  errors='{[0]}'id='500c0000002IDQnAAO' success='true'], [SaveResult  errors='{[0]}' id='500c0000002IDQoAAO' success='true']]
```

It looks like in Apex you can reference these however, I don't know if there is an equivalent way in Mule, or in one of the supported scripting engines like Groovy.   If I cannot access the values, could I use Groovy string operations to find all where a start tag is "id='" and a end tag is "'" and then join them?

Comment: Are you sure that's not just the `toString()` of a `SaveResult` object?  If it is, you should be able to do `results.id`

Comment: And also use a MEL projection to extract all these IDs in a new list: http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Projections+and+Folds

Comment: Thank you @tim_yates and @David-Dossot! payload.id in groovy worked great!  
'code' payload.id is [500c0000002IDTmAAO, 500c0000002IDTnAAO]

Comment: Added as an answer. Glad it worked!

Comment: Cool, no need to use Groovy, unless you're on Mule < 3.3

Answer (score 0):

That's just the String representation of the payload. The create operation returns a List of SaveResults. You can easily access these using MEL/MVEL. Here is an example that grabs all Ids and puts them into a new list as a flow variable:

```
<sfdc:create ... />

<expression-component>
 flowVars.ids = (Id in payload)
</expression-component>

<logger level="INFO"  message="Ids = #[flowVars.ids]" />
```

You should see something like: Ids= ['xxxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz']

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's not just the `toString()` of a list of `SaveResult` object?

If it is, you should be able to do `results.id`